# Why does my function not detect the values of an array correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently making a tictactoe game on React, and was writing a function to detect if a player has won. This is what my App.js looks like

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import {useState,setState} from 'react';
import {useEffect} from 'react'
import Board from './components/Board';

function App() {
  const [board, setBoard] = useState([])
  const [currentTurn,setCurrentTurn] = useState('')
  const [gameOver, setGameOver]= useState(false)

  function checkWin() {
   const winConditions = [
    [0,3,6],[1,4,7],[2,4,8],
    [0,4,8],[2,4,6],
    [0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]
   ]


   for (let j=0; j < winConditions.length; j++) {
    if (board[winConditions[j][0]].value === '')
      return 
    
    if (board[winConditions[j][0]] == board[winConditions[j][1]] == board[winConditions[j][2]]) {
      setGameOver(true)
      console.log(`Game Over! ${currentTurn} has won`)
     }
    }
  } 


  function populateObject() {

    let mockarray = []

    for (let i=0; i < 9; i++) {

      mockarray.push({num: i, value:''})

    }

    setBoard([...mockarray])
    setCurrentTurn('x')
  }

  function fillCell(event) {
    const cell = event.target;
    board[cell.id] = {id: cell.id, value: currentTurn}
    setBoard([...board])
    checkWin()
    currentTurn == 'x' ? setCurrentTurn('o') : setCurrentTurn('x')
  }

  useEffect(()=> {
    populateObject()
  },[])



  return (
    <div className="App">
     <Board fillFunction = {fillCell} currentTurn={currentTurn} valuearray={board}></Board>
     <button onClick={populateObject}>Reset</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and this is my Board Component

```
import '../stylesheets/board.css'

function Board({valuearray, currentTurn,fillFunction}) {

    function insertSymbol(value) {
        var content
        switch(value) {
            case 'x':
                content = <i className='fa solid fa-x'></i>
                break;
                
            case 'o' :
                content =  <i className='fa solid fa-o'></i>
                break;

            default:
                content = ''
                break;
        }


        return content

    }
    
    
    return(
        <div className="board-section">
            <div className='turn-header'>
             <h4>It is currently {currentTurn}'s turn</h4>
            </div>
            <div className='board'>
                {valuearray.map(v=> {
                    
                    return(
                        <div className="cell" id={v.num} onClick={fillFunction}>
                            {
                             insertSymbol(v.value)
                            }                      
                        </div>
                    )
                })}

            </div>
            

        </div>
    )
  



}


export default Board;
```

Whenever I input in a winning condition (as either X or O), the winning condition code does not execute at all. Can anyone find a solution to this? thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove the `return` from the `for` loop? Using `return` will exit your function and stop your loop as soon as the condition is true for your `if` statement, which will occur if nothing is in the top-left box

Comment: @Kevin-H check [react docs](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html) they also show how to made `tic-tac-toe game`.

Comment: Your `if (board[winConditions` condition is incorrect.  Instead of `a == b == c` you want `a == b && b == c`.  Also change the `return` to a `continue` as @NickParsons pointed out.

Comment: @NickParsons unfortunately the code still didnt work. I got three x's in a diagonal and yet the print statement still didnt run (I removed 'return' and added 'continue' in its place)

Comment: @KevinH You also need to fix your if-statement like user2740650 pointed out so that you use `&&`. Another issue is that `board[winConditions[j][0]] == board[winConditions[j][1]]` won't be true, you need to check the `value`, eg: `board[winConditions[j][0]].value == board[winConditions[j][1]].value`

Comment: @NickParsons I cant believe i missed that one, ty for the fix mate

Comment: @user2740650 appreciated your help too!

Answer (score 1):

```js
function populateObject() {
  let mockarray = []
  for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    // check here you are storing as an object and 
    // object props is {num and value}
    mockarray.push({
      num: i,
      value: ''
    })
  }
  setBoard([...mockarray])
  setCurrentTurn('x')
}

function fillCell(event) {
  const cell = event.target;
  // check here where are you trying to store the clicked cell id

  // here id is string value, not string 
  // board[cell.id] = {id: cell.id, value: currentTurn}

  // Need to update 
  const cellId = parseInt(event.target.id, 10); // make it integer 
  board[cellId] = {
    num: cellId,
    value: currentTurn
  }

  setBoard([...board])
  checkWin()
  currentTurn == 'x' ? setCurrentTurn('o') : setCurrentTurn('x')
}




// Updated code like below  
import './App.css';
import {
  useState,
  useEffect
} from 'react';
import Board from './Board';

const winConditions = [
  [0, 3, 6],
  [1, 4, 7],
  [2, 4, 8],
  [0, 4, 8],
  [2, 4, 6],
  [0, 1, 2],
  [3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8]
];

// App.jsx
function App() {
  const [board, setBoard] = useState([]);
  const [currentTurn, setCurrentTurn] = useState('');
  const [gameOver, setGameOver] = useState(false);

  function checkWin() {
    for (let j = 0; j < winConditions.length; j++) {
      if (board[winConditions[j][0]].value === '')
        return

      if (board[winConditions[j][0]] === board[winConditions[j][1]] === board[winConditions[j][2]]) {
        setGameOver(true)
        console.log(`Game Over! ${currentTurn} has won`)
      }
    }
  }

  function populateObject() {
    let mockarray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
      mockarray.push({
        num: i,
        value: ''
      })
    }
    setBoard(mockarray)
    setCurrentTurn('x')
  }

  function fillCell(event) {
    const cellId = parseInt(event.target.id, 10);
    board[cellId] = {
      num: cellId,
      value: currentTurn
    }
    setBoard([...board])
    checkWin()
    currentTurn === 'x' ? setCurrentTurn('o') : setCurrentTurn('x')
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    populateObject()
  }, [])



  return ( <
    div className = "App" >
    <
    Board valuearray = {
      board
    }
    currentTurn = {
      currentTurn
    }
    fillFunction = {
      fillCell
    }
    /> <
    button onClick = {
      populateObject
    } > Reset < /button> <
    /div>
  );
}

export default App;

// Board.jsx
const symbols = {
  'x': < i className = 'fa solid fa-x' > X < /i>, / / should be font awsome icon 'o': < i className = 'fa solid fa-o' > O < /i> / / should be font awsome icon
}


function Board({
  valuearray,
  currentTurn,
  fillFunction
}) {
  return ( <
    div className = "board-section" >
    <
    div className = 'turn-header' >
    <
    h4 > It is currently {
      currentTurn
    }
    's turn</h4> <
    /div> <
    div className = 'board' > {
      valuearray.map(v => {
        return ( <
          div key = {
            v.num
          }
          className = "cell"
          id = {
            v.num
          }
          onClick = {
            fillFunction
          } > {
            symbols[v.value]
          } <
          /div>
        )
      })
    }

    <
    /div> <
    /div>
  )
}
export default Board;
```